# Granular control over JSON-LD embeddings

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, json-ld

Given the following JSON-LD

```json
{
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "Alice",
      "https://schema.org/givenName": "Alice",
      "https://schema.org/familyName": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "@id": "CorporationA",
      "https://schema.org/founder": [
        {
          "@id": "Alice"
        }
      ],
      "https://schema.org/member": [
        {
          "@id": "Alice"
        }
      ],
      "https://schema.org/employee": [
        {
          "@id": "Alice"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

with the simple frame

```json
{
  "@vocab": "https://schema.org/"
}
```

is it possible to have more granular control over the embeddings than what's provided via `@embed` (that is `@once`, `@always`, and `@never`)? More precisely, say I wanted to have an embedding only for the `member` property, but not for `founder` or `employee`. Is it possible without reordering the fields?

From the JSON-LD specification, I only gather that it is possible to use `@embed`, setting it to either `@once`, `@always`, or `@never`. However I would like to have more precise control over the embeddings.

Comment: `{ "@context": { "@vocab": "https://schema.org/" },
  "@embed": "@never",
  "member" : { "@embed": "@always" }
}` — ?

Comment: @StanislavKralin that works, yes; I tried using `@embed` on `member` but did not use `@never` at top level. I think I will have to set the `@never` at field level rather then for everything in my actual case, but that should be ok. If you add this as a answer I will close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works in JSON-LD Playground:

```json
{
  "@context": { "@vocab": "https://schema.org/" },
  "@embed": "@never",  
  "member" : { "@embed": "@always" }
}
```

The result (with `compactArrays` set to `true`) is:

```json
{
  "@context": { "@vocab": "https://schema.org/" },
  "@id": "CorporationA",
  "employee": { "@id": "Alice" },
  "founder": { "@id": "Alice" },
  "member": {
    "@id": "Alice",
    "familyName": "Smith",
    "givenName": "Alice"
  }
}
```

Note that the default value for `@embed` is `once`.